# Does JNI Throw break the method execution?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

When I call `env->ThrowNew(clazz, "...")`, will the subsequent execution of the C++/C method be stopped or do I have to stop it myself?

```cpp
// This is the method which checks if a class can be loaded.

static inline jclass _check_find_class(JNIEnv* env, char* name) {
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass(name);

    if (clazz == NULL) {
        env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass("java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError"), message);
    }

    return clazz;
}

// This method is called in other functions like

jclass load_main_class(JNIEnv* env) {
    auto clazz = _check_find_class(env, "class/which/cannot/be/loaded");

    do_stuff(env, clazz);

    return clazz;
}
```

What is going to happen when I call `load_main_class` method, it isn't able to find the class and the `ThrowNew` method is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JNI exception [does not immediately disrupt the native method execution](http://web.archive.org/web/20080601040320/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/exceptions.html). But if you don't handle this exception correctly, then any JNI function call (except the very few ones that are explicitly cleared) will crash.

Answer (score 2):

> What is going to happen when I call `load_main_class` method, it isn't
>   able to find the class and the `ThrowNew` method is called?

In your particular case the `NoClassDefFoundError` that was pending right after `env->FindClass(name)` returned `NULL` will be overwritten by your hand-throwing exception `env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass("java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError"), message)` which will be thrown when control is transferred back to Java code.

What you described is an improper way of handling exception in JNI code. You should have checked it with `env->ExceptionOccurred();` and then call `env->ExceptionClear()` to indicate that the exception was handled.